# Get ShaXXX of a GO Package

Tags: go, sha

I Need to get the Sha512 or similar from a Golang package for SBOM purposes.
For example, the hash for package
https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json

I can't found any information or api to get it. If possible I need it without download the source code.

Comment: `encoding/json` is part of the standard library. Check the hash of your [go binary release](https://golang.org/dl/) and you should have an untampered codebase for the standard library packages.

Comment: for implementation details https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/mod/sumdb/dirhash and more https://golang.org/ref/mod#authenticating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [sum.golang.org](https://sum.golang.org/) which is

> an auditable checksum database which will be used by the go command to
> authenticate modules.

you can read more on how it works on [this post](https://go.dev/blog/module-mirror-launch#checksum-database) from go blog

Comment: also this https://golang.org/ref/mod#checksum-database

Comment: `sum.golang.org` works for [external packages](https://sum.golang.org/lookup/golang.org/x/text@v0.3.2) but not for internal packages like `encoding/json`.

Comment: @colm.anseo in fact those packages does not even exist in that database ? `$ curl http://sum.golang.org/lookup/encoding/json@v0.0.0` => `bad request: invalid escaped module path "encoding/json": malformed module path "encoding/json": missing dot in first path element`. They dont have version, their package paths are specials.

Comment: @mh-cbon they do have a "version" - it's just implicitly tied to the `go version`.